# inner join not working in one to one mapping spring data jpa

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

i have to entity objects and there is a one to one mapping between them

```
@Data
@Entity(name= "mv_garage_asset_mapping")
public class GarageAssetMapping implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2535545189473989744L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="GARAGE_CODE")
    private String garageCode;

    @Column(name="CONTRACT_NUMBER")
    private String contractNumber;

    @OneToOne( fetch=FetchType.LAZY )
    @JoinColumn(name="CONTRACT_NUMBER", referencedColumnName = "hpano", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    private RepoAgentDetails repoAgentDetails;
}
```

the other entity is

```
@Entity 
public class RepoAgentDetails {
   @Column(name="hpano")
   private String hpano;
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "repoAgentDetails",   fetch = FetchType.LAZY)  
    private GarageAssetMapping garageAssetMapping;
}
```

there is one to one mapping and iam using inner join to get data from the table
when i run the inner join the spring data jpa does not give any result although query is getting fired and there is no exception in the code.

how ever when i run the query on database using sqldeveloper tool the query gives the result but when the same query in the code it does not give any result

the query is as follows

```
@Query("select new com.mf.acrs.garage.bean.AssetDetailsBean (ga.contractNumber as contractNumber, ra.create_date as createDate ) "
            + "from mv_garage_asset_mapping ga "
            + " inner join RepoAgentDetails ra on ga.contractNumber = ra.hpano"
            + " where ga.garageCode = ?1 ")     


    List<AssetDetailsBean> findByGarageCode ( String garageCode );
```

can any one help me to track the issue..

Comment: You query looks like SQL but mixed with JPQL. You cannot use NEW with SQL

Comment: can you modify the query in the form of JPQL or give me a link? However when i use the same query to apply join with other  table it gives the result but join with this table does not fetch any result althoug data is present..thats is why i was confused

Answer (score 0):

The query should look like this (because you didn't provide all attributes from the entities it's a guess)

```
@Query("select new com.mf.acrs.garage.bean.AssetDetailsBean (ga.contractNumber, ga.repoAgentDetails.create_date) "
            + "from GarageAssetMapping ga where ga.garageCode = ?1")     
List<AssetDetailsBean> findByGarageCode (String garageCode);
```